# Core Image UISlider Performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I'm having a bit of a problem with my code. As suggested in other questions on the stackoverflow I've created the following strong properties:

- EAGLContext
- CIContext
- CIImage for input image
- CIImage for output image
- NSDictionary for options
- UImageView
- UISlider

In my viewDidLoad I have the following code:

```
_inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:self.imageView.image];

_filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"];
[_filter setValue:_inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[_filter setValue:@0 forKey:kCIInputIntensityKey];

_eaglContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

_options = @{ kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null] };
_context = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:_eaglContext options:_options];

[_filterSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And my valueChanged: method:

```
NSLog(@"Slider value: %f", sender.value);
[_filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sender.value] forKey:kCIInputIntensityKey];
_outputImage = [_filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[_context createCGImage:_outputImage fromRect:_outputImage.extent]];
```

Even though the slider works sort of smooth but when I move the slider from side to side after a few slider movements I receive a memory warning and the entire app crashes.

Any idea what this problem might be ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Time to run your app in the Leaks Instrument and see if you can find a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just as you expected there are some memory leaks. Back to the drawing board, I guess.

Comment: The leaks tool should give you enough information to find the leaks. If you drill down and click on an individual leaked object it shows you the source line where it's allocated, which is usually enough for you to figure out how its being leaked.

Comment: OK, so the problem was not the code but rather the size of images. All I had to do was using the CGImageCreateWithImageInRect or CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex to scale down the image. Thanks for your help, Duncan.